# Incompatible module packages need to be solved

Tags: python, module

Well, I ran into two troubles when I want to install the modules. The first one is

```
1) statsmodels 0.13.2 has requirement packaging>=21.3, but you have packaging 20.9.
2) tensorflowjs 3.19.0 requires packaging~=20.9, but you have packaging 21.3 which is incompatible.
```

The second one is

```
1)sktime 0.11.0 has requirement numba>=0.53, but you have numba 0.49.0.
2)ddsp 3.2.0 requires numba<0.50, but you have numba 0.56.0 which is incompatible.
```

They are both conflicting, and I don't know how to do so.

Comment: One solution would be to find a version of sktime that works with numba 0.49.0 or later and a version of statsmodels that works with packaging 20.9 or later. Replace your current versions with those older versions and you should be able to run (or run into the next similar constraint - rinse, lather, repeat). A tool like `pipdeptree` can help you figure out what the dependencies are of packages you have already installed.

Comment: Thanks, is there any method I can check a version of sktime that works with numba 0.49.0?

Comment: No easy ones that I'm aware of, unless you have access to a source repository for those versions (and can check requirements from there). However, I would just create a temporary virtual environment and take a guess, install an older version and use `pipdeptree` to see if it meets my needs. You should be able to get the best version with only a few guesses and uninstall/reinstall tries.

Comment: Okay, I'll give a try. Because after typing pipdeptree, it ran so many lines that I am really confused